# expo run:android is stuck at blank white screen

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, expo-go

[image: 1]

As seen in the above image, after successfully building for android, the standalone app is installed on the device but when opened, *before showing the Splash screen, the blank white screen appears.*

**This is my App.js code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import StackNavigator from "./StackNavigator";
import { AuthProvider } from "./hooks/useAuth";
import { ActivityIndicator, LogBox, View } from "react-native";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import {
  Roboto_100Thin,
  Roboto_100Thin_Italic,
  Roboto_300Light,
  Roboto_300Light_Italic,
  useFonts,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/roboto";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import * as encoding from "text-encoding";

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

function cacheImages(images) {
  return images.map((image) => {
    if (typeof image === "string") {
      return Image.prefetch(image);
    } else {
      return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
    }
  });
}
function cacheFonts(fonts) {
  return fonts.map((font) => Font.loadAsync(font));
}

export default function App() {
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(true);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Roboto-Thin": Roboto_100Thin,
    Roboto_100Thin_Italic,
    "Roboto-Light": Roboto_300Light,
    Roboto_300Light_Italic,
  });

  async function _loadAssetsAsync() {
    const imageAssets = await cacheImages([
      require("./ASSETS/Loading_Black.gif"),
      require("./ASSETS/icons/like.png"),
      require("./ASSETS/icons/like-red.png"),
      require("./ASSETS/icons/comment.png"),
      require("./ASSETS/icons/share.png"),
      require("./ASSETS/CHAT_BGRD-02.jpeg"),
    ]);

    await Promise.all([...imageAssets, fontsLoaded]);
  }

  return ready && fontsLoaded ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthProvider>
          <StackNavigator />
      </AuthProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <AppLoading
      startAsync={_loadAssetsAsync}
      onFinish={() => setReady(true)}
      onError={(e) => {
        console.log(e);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The app is perfectly running on development mode, production mode, and even tried using

```
expo start --no-dev --minify
```

All these are perfectly working fine. But if I try to run the app in standalone mode, this is what's the output is. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen, I updated android studio, updated android studio's sdk tools: Android emulator, hypervisor,  platform tools, etc.

Then I re-made the devices in the Virtual Device Manager and then re-ran "expo start --android" and it worked.